# WebApi OData 4 , second POST endpoint for bulk insertion in the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I have a basic WebApi OData 4 controller for TEAM model which has a POST action for adding a new TEAM to the database.

```
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(USER_TEAMS userTeam)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        context.USER_TEAMS.Add(userTeam);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Created(userTeam);
    }
```

I want to have another endpoint in that controller for **bulk insertion** of teams which takes a list of team objects and adds them to the database. What is the best approach in WebApi OData 4 to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OData spec includes a [batching](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part1-protocol-complete.html#_Toc406398359) concept, but for this problem an [OData action](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/odata-actions-and-functions) is a cleaner solution. The action will be bound to the Teams entity set and will accept a collection of `Team` entities in the request payload. (I've changed `USER_TEAMS` to `Team` in the code below.)

Given the following simple definition of `Team` entity type:

```
public class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

First, define the action method in the same controller as your `Post` method.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult BulkAdd(ODataActionParameters parameters)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        var newTeams = (IEnumerable<Team>)parameters["NewTeams"];

        // Your data access layer logic goes here.

        return this.StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }
```

Then declare the OData action in your Web API configuration code.

```
    var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

    builder.Namespace = "TeamService";
    builder.EntitySet<Team>("Teams");
    builder.EntityType<Team>().Collection
        .Action("BulkAdd")
        .CollectionParameter<Team>("NewTeams");
```

Note in the above:

- `EntityTypeConfiguration<T>.Collection` is necessary to bind the action to the `Team` entity set (vs. a single `Team` entity)
- `ActionConfiguration.CollectionParameter<T>` is necessary to specify that the parameter is a collection (vs. a scalar)

On the client, invoke the action as follows.

```
POST http://domain/Teams/TeamService.BulkAdd
Content-Type: application/json

{"NewTeams": [{"Name": "Demons"}, {"Name": "Angels"}]}
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks!  see my related questions here, in case it can help someone find this great answer. : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67411075/c-sharp-webapi-odata-post-endpoint-with-ienumerable-in-parameters-return-error-4/67411076#67411076