# C# OData Web API POST endpoint with IEnumerable in parameters returns error 400 the input was not valid

Tags: c#, odata, webapi

I have a spooky behavior here. I have a controller here (I have cheated and obfuscated a lot of stuff here... it is still relevant)

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController] 
public class MyComplexTypeController : ControllerBase
{ 
    //context...
    public MyComplexTypeController()
    {
        //context..
    }
        
    [HttpPost] 
    // For simplicity, I have renamed the endpoint..  
    // In reality I just have ONE Post endpoint here
    public ActionResult MyCallThatWorks(MyComplexObj param_origData) 
    {
        // The param_origData is GREAT and working!
        return Ok();   
    }

    [HttpPost]
    // For simplicity, I have renamed the endpoint.
    // In reality I just have ONE Post endpoint here
    public ActionResult MyCallThatDontWorks(IEnumerable<MyComplexObj> param_origData)
    {
        // I get a 400 "The input was not valid." in PostMan! 
        return Ok();
    }
```

And here you have the `startup.cs` :

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup2)); 
        services.AddCors();
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddOData();
        services.AddControllers()
            //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-5.0
            .AddJsonOptions(options => 
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);
        
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials().AllowAnyHeader().SetIsOriginAllowed(x => true));
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.Select().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Count().MaxTop(null);
            endpoints.MapODataRoute("odata", "api", MyGetEdmModel());
        }); 
    }

    private static IEdmModel MyGetEdmModel()
    {
        ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<MyComplexObj>("MyComplexType");
        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
}
```

In fact I have 3 complex types with 3 endpoints. Two of my endpoint work correctly with OData.

My third type, the one explained here, works also (GET, POST, DELETE) !

**BUT**: the `POST` of my endpoint only works if I pass ONE instance of my complex class. It will NOT work if I pass an `IEnumerable` (and correctly pass data in Postman `[ { "bla":12" }, { "bla":24 }]`.

I tried a loooooot of stuff. Just to name a few:

1. Remove the `[ApiController]` in the controller attribute (I don't find the link sorry..) - didn't work : I was getting a `NULL` value in my params (but still, was entering the method)
2. Tried passing a DTO instead (same problem - error 400)
3. Tried to create a pass a dynamic/object/string in param (ugly and have to fight to convert it back)
4. Tried OData Actions and Odata CollectionParameter function (didn't survive this one)  - **EDIT** : that was the solution!
5. Tried to pass it `[FromBody]`, and without `[FromBody]` (so xxx-form-encoded) - was entering in the method, but got `NULL`!
6. In Postman, I tried using

   ```
     {"":[{"Mycollection":"Of"},{"Complex":"Objet"}]}
   ```

   and also tried

   ```
    =[{"Mycollection":"Of"},{"Complex":"Objet"}]
   ```

   (as stated somewhere in MS docs..ahah)
7. I did the standard 'Why Odata is so shitty' in Google, was going to try GraphQL, but I did resist...

I finally did what a clever coder must do: I restarted from the base.

Long story SHORT : OData was not tolerating that my param signature did not match the initial routing.

So I had to remove this line in my `Startup.cs` :

```
private static IEdmModel MyGetEdmModel()
{
        ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<MyComplexObj>("MyComplexType");   <--THIS ONE
        builder.EntitySet<OtherComplexType>("OtherComplexType");
        builder.EntitySet<OtherComplexType2>("OtherComplexType2");
        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
```

and it was working great with passing an `IEnumerable`!

**QUESTION** : why?

Now, I cannot do a full OData fetch on that particular entity (cannot find the services container for the non-OData route). That's normal, I just removed it!

Answer (score -1):

I JUST found this one (after writing my post) :
[WebApi OData 4 , second POST endpoint for bulk insertion in the controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35508355/webapi-odata-4-second-post-endpoint-for-bulk-insertion-in-the-controller)

Seems to be the answer, and keeping every thing 'OData approved'!

So big picture, to be able to POST a TYPE that is different than the OData type registered, you have to create a new endpoint (method), called Action. This action can than take whatever type you define (in startup.cs):

```
private static IEdmModel MyGetEdmModel()
{
        ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<xxx>("xx");
        builder.EntitySet<yyyy>("yyy");
        builder.EntitySet<MyComplexType>("MyComplexType");

        // added this line here:
        builder.EntityType<MyComplexType>().Collection
              .Action("BulkAdd")
              .CollectionParameter<MyComplexType>("MyXREF");

        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
```

and then, in the method of the controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> BulkAdd(ODataActionParameters parameters)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        } 

        List<MycomplexType> bookings = ((IEnumerable<MycomplexType>)parameters["MyXREF"]).ToList();
```

ET VOILA!